# SWOT .NET 2 to .NET 4

Tags: .net, asp.net

What are the Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities and Threats by migrating a Web Application from .Net 2 to .Net 4 ?
This application is using Ado.Net and stored procedures.

Comment: Not sure, but seems like the folks at [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) will be happy to have this question.

Comment: Never mind. Seems like SWOT is a business matter. I thought it was security strengths, security weaknesses, security threats, etc. Bah, off-topic then. Mods, please ignore what I wrote in my flag.

Comment: I've been voting to close because the question is not answerable for two reasons: First, we don't know your application. Second, we can't know all possibilities (I mean, Jon Skeet maybe does (that wasn't a joke on my side, I really meant that, I mean he has really deep knowledge of .NET)). Third, the question is argumentative and subjective.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since .Net 3.5 you can use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324).

Besides .Net 4.0 has more features you can use.

Only disadvantage is that when you publish it you need to make sure the target machine has .Net 4.0.

Comment: And that your App Pool is set to .NET 4.0 and not 2.0.